# Way to make textarea fill entire cell in a table

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have designed this table for reporters to browse information about their reports in the database, and the textareas at the top function as both search fields and table heads -- which show what is in each column.

However, a problem I have run into is that when the table shifts dimensions because of content, the textareas (obviously) do not shift along with them.

My question is this; is there a way to force the textarea take up the entire area of the cell they are in?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/twOmA.png]

Comment: Did you try something like this in your css file?
textarea {
width: 100%;
}

Comment: Trying that now, looks a bit promising.

Comment: Please see attached for answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55047958/make-textarea-fill-table-cells-height/63098674#63098674

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
textarea {
   width: 100%;
}
```

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/ravan/JZwhH/